# Сброс аутентификационных данных админки для всех устройств

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, администрирование, защита

Дело в том, что я пытаюсь реализовать админ-часть сайта, чтобы в нее можно было войти с различных устройств.

При первом входе в админку посредством логина и пароля на устройстве устанавливается cookie (на 365 дней), а ее хэш размещается в отдельной таблице БД. При  вводе таких же логина и пароля с других устройств, на них также устанавливаются cookie. Все cookie различны для разных устройств, поэтому при очередном входе в админ-часть скрипт сканирует таблицу БД с cookie-хэшами. Если совпадение найдено - устанавливается сессия - ввод логина/пароля не требуется.

Все просто.
Но как быть, если третье лицо получит доступ к логин и паролю? Злоумышленник введет их на своем устройстве и получит доступ к админке. Конечно, при обнаружении этого, администратор может тут же поменять логин и пароль в БД и удалить таблицу c cookies, но у злоумышленника остается сессионная переменная и он может творить все что вздумается до окончания сессии.

Какие есть пути решения данной проблемы? На широкоизвестных веб-площадках при изменении аутентификационных данных пользователя, на других устройствах сессия тут же  обрывается.

Comment: Разве компрометация пароля не повод сбросить всё, что можно? Да и после смены пароля сброс сессии просто обязателен.

Comment: @Other, как сбросить сессию на всех устройствах, где были установлены сессии и куки?

Comment: Зачем это делать? Очистите таблицу валидных сессий и теперь любое устройство с сессией просто будет получать ответ "Сессия не валидна" и редирект на страницу входа/вставь своё.

Comment: Впервые столкнулся. Таблицу с сессиями что ли сделать? При каждом обновлении страницы сверять сессию с табличными данными?

Comment: Примерно так: Генерируется сессионный ключ, сохраняется в БД (если нужно хранить подольше), при каждом запросе сверяется полученного ключа с наличием его в БД. Найден - значит запрос был когда-то аутентифицирован и всё ещё годный, пускаем без пароля. Если ключа в БД (таблице сессий) нет - пущай аутентифицируется заново.

Comment: Сессии в php по умолчанию хранятся в файле указанном в `session.save_path`. Очищаете этот файл - и нет больше сессий.

Comment: `session_destroy` вообще храните сессию 10 минут к примеру нет активности так и сесию убиваем.

Comment: @vp_arth, я имел ввиду не механизм сессий в PHP, а механизм временной авторизации по ключу на N времени, что тоже сессия. Да и очищать весь файл с валидными **чужими** сессиям - глупо.

Comment: Глупо - не глупо, иногда это наиболее быстрый способ вернуть онлайн после компрометации.

Comment: @vp_arth, если масштабная утечка - одним сбросом сессий не обойдёшься (но да, файлик можно сбросить в нуль), а если только один пользователь попался, но другие 300 хотят чтобы они нормально входили и через ПК, и через смартфон? Объяснять им что из-за сброса сессий Васи Пупкина нужно и им заново создать сессию?

Comment: @Other, понятно - в критическом случае скрип чистит все сессии и куки в БД, кроме данных админа. Доступа извне уже нет. За это время админ меняет логин, пароль и т.д. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: А если скомпрометирован админ? Сбрасывайте только тех, кто сбросил пароль/потерял. Если есть подозрение на массовость - что ж, сбросьте всё, зайдите владельцем через SSH и ищите дыру, куда всё утекло. Потом можно открыть общий вход (с принудительным сбросом паролей, конечно).

Comment: Если проект в стадии разработки - нужно более комплексно подходить к безопасности. У пользователя должна быть возможность включить двухфакторную аутентификацию, разлогиниться на всех девайсах кроме текущего и т.д., и т.п. Полагаться на стандартный механизм сессий я бы вообще не стал. Одна кука не должна давать доступ ко всему. Должна быть как минимум доп.авторизация к критичным секциям, таким как редактирование профиля...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну для решения сбрасывания всех текущих сессий пользователя со всех устройств, очевидно, нужно иметь связь сессии и пользователя.
В той же таблице с хешами для разных устройств вы можете хранить и `user_id` для каждой сессии. Как только происходит смена пароля для конкретного `user_id` в таблице хешей удаляются все записи для это пользователя по его id.

По тому же принципу можно реализовать и кнопку в админке "Отключить все устройства (сессии) кроме текущей\включая текущую"

Comment: Логин и пароль будут в единственном экземпляре. Поэтому кнопка - "отключить устройства" будет точно удалять все сессии, кроме единственной - настоящего админа. Как определить - админ за устройством или злоумышленник? Думаю, что удаление всех сессий должно происходить с емейл-подтверждением. Так?

Comment: Нет, и админа тоже пусть выбрасывает, если он поменял только что пароль, пусть заново его введет и продолжит работу. Либо еще интересный вариант смотреть с какого ip пришел запрос на смену пароля и только эту сессию оставлять. А на тему "Как определить - админ за устройством или злоумышленник" очень сложно ответить, даже гугл порой не справляется с подобной задачей. Тут уже надо вести тотальную слежку за пользователем и определять его стандартное поведение (в какое время он заходит, с каких ip и тп) и при отклонении от нормы использовать силу двухфакторной авторизации

Comment: Сейчас у большинства людей динамический ip.  Буду привязывать именно к емейл. Да, нужно сбрасывать все сессии, и админа тоже.